# Silex / Symfony programmatically login

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am using the Silex / Symfony security service and try to implement a automatic login when the specific parameters are passed in the request query.

I've looked into the modules and also search on the internet for a solution and always found something like the following:

```
$user = (new \Portal\UserProvider($app['databases']['read']))->loadUserByUsername($subscriber_id);
$token = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured', $user->getRoles());
$app['security.token_storage']->setToken($token);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for my app. I don't know whats wrong but the security module keeps redirecting me to /login/ as specified in the registration process:

```
/**
 * Registers the security firewall.
 */
private function registerSecurity()
{
    $this->register(new \Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls'    => array(
            'login'     => array(
                'pattern' => '^/(login/|terms|imprint|animation|error)',
            ),
            'secured'   => array(
                'pattern'   => '^/',
                'form'      => array(
                    'login_path'    => '/login/',
                    'check_path'    => '/login_check'
                ),
                'logout'    => array(
                    'logout_path' => '/logout'
                ),
                'users'   => $this->share(function () {
                    return new \Portal\UserProvider($this['databases']['read']);
                }),
            ),
            'unsecured' => array(
                'anonymous' => true
            ),
        ),
        'security.encoder.digest'   => $this->share(function () {
            return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha1', false, 1);
        }),
        'security.access_rules'     => array(
            array('^/login', 'ROLE_GUEST'),
        ),
        'security.role_hierarchy'   =>  $this->share(function () {
            return array();
        })
    ));

    $this->boot();
}
```

Is there anything I have to consider about

- reloading
- order of registering the `SecurityServiceProvider`, `SessionServiceProvider`
- this manual token setting

?

Comment: maybe useful? : [The RememberMeServiceProvider adds "Remember-Me" authentication to the SecurityServiceProvider.](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/remember_me.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 'form' authentication provider, but this won't work (or maybe I'm not understanding you correctly?). In order to be able to:

> try to implement a automatic login when the specific parameters are passed in the request query

You need to hook into the Security service. In order to do that you have to create a [Listener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ListenerInterface.php) and register it. You'll also need a [Provider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/AuthenticationProviderInterface.php)

This is not an easy path as the security component works with many concepts.

You can see a working example [in this repo](https://github.com/gigablah/silex-oauth/tree/master/src) (which implements an OAuth service)

If your security flow is easy and you don't need roles, you can just use a before middleware (and forget about the security component) like so:

```
<?php

$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if (false === $session->get('logged', false)) {
        if (null !== $request->get('blah', null)) {
            $session->set('logged', true);
        }
        else {
            return new RedirectResponse('/login-url');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have made a walk around using session and an own mechanism via the middleware. But this does not answer my question. I have found multiple pages where people used the very same technique as described above with creating a Token etc. and it worked for them. Even in the unit test modules they use the same way. So I must have been doing something wrong. And I would like to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Silex's guard. It works well with get Request. And standard form could be use as complement.

In your `secured` Security.firwall, add the guard parameter :

```
"guard" => array ("authenticator" => array("app.myauthenticator") )
```

And create your custom class, to validate login.

Just read the [Silex cookbook](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/cookbook/guard_authentication.html).